# Drupal 7 - image module and contrib module

Tags: drupal, image-processing, drupal-7

I wrote a module with "image" in dependecies. But I can't use the functions in image.gd.php
Apache log:
 Call to undefined function image_gd_save()

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this outside of the normal operation of the image/system modules you'll need to make sure the relevant file is included first:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'system', 'image.gd');
```

Comment: Ah ok...it's not part of the image module and the file's not called image.gd.php, it's called image.gd.inc. I've edited the answer, I've tested that code and it works well